# RegEx Matching Help

Tags: java, regex

Here is the input string:

```
#video:firstVideo.mp4#
#video:secondVideo.mp4 title:Title of second Video#
#video:thirdVideo.mp4#
```

I want to match all of the above lines (the *title:* attribute is **optional**). However, the Java RegEx below will only match the **second** line.

> ```
> (?<=#)video:(.*?).mp4\stitle:(.*?)(?=#)
> ```

How can I correct this RegEx to make the *title:* attribute **optional** and will return all three lines? I will vote for whoever has a working/efficient answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to put the optional title part into a non-capturing group followed by a `?` to make it optional:

```
(?<=#)video:(.*?).mp4(?:\stitle:(.*?))?(?=#)
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
    (?<=#)video:(.*?).mp4(\stitle:(.*?))?(?=#)
```

Or just:

```
    #video:(.*?).mp4(?:\stitle:.*?)?#
```

See [rubular](http://rubular.com/r/ePrnBkspFa).

It depends what you want to have in your matching groups.